# JQuery inserts "localhost" before href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am using the following:

```
let string = `${item.link}`;
let sliced = string.substring(0, 15)

$(".list").append(
  `<li>
    <span class="link"><a href="${item.link}" target="_blank">${sliced}...</a> 
    </span>
   </li>
  `)
```

When rendered, the page links to `localhost/www.website.com` (local development). In actual deployment localhost becomes the whole URL. How do I lose the pre-tag?

Comment: You need to include a protocol.

Comment: `href="//${item.link}"` or update `item` so that `item.link` includes a scheme.

Comment: @SLaks The link comes with a full protocol. I.e: the written out item.link looks like http://bla.com

Comment: @Paulpro thank, you the `//` did it. Where can I read up information about this method ?

Comment: https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/